# how can i import image from facebook in iphone application development?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, import

How can I import images from facebook albums in an iphone application ? Any suggestion, any code or any link is appreciable. 
I have seen couple of such questions on stack overflow but I have not got my desired answer. I have seen the facebook api link help, so any tutorial link would also be helpful.

NOTE THAT: Till now I can share an image to facebook. So there is no problem on fbconnect till now.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: take a look at this tutorial http://photo-slideshow-director.com/blog/import-facebook-photos-into-iphone-and-create-a-slideshow/ , hopefully helpful

Comment: @iMeMyself What link have you given and for what purpose ?

Comment: oops,@Gill i thought its a tutorial to create FB album in iphone app if this doesnt work for im sorry..